# Typescript union string literal in another union type

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements

```
type Status = 'Active' | 'Pending' | 'Failed';

type User = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  status: 'active' // how to get autocomplete, it's lowercase??
} | {
  error: string;
  id: string;
  status: 'failed' // can it be something like Status['Failed']
} |
{
  id: string;
  status: 'pending'
}
```

Given `Status` as string union type, sometimes there is need to use the type in another complex object type.
Different field structure for each status values.

How to make sure type safety when creating the `User` with `status` field?

I would like to reuse same type, something like below

```
const fooBarFn(status: Status) {
  if (status === 'Pending') {
    return {
      id: '123',
      status
    }
  }
  // rest of fn
}
```

*Are there any other patterns or best practices for the above?*

**some solution**

```
type RecordX<K extends keyof any> = {
  [P in K]: P;
};

type Status = 'Active' | 'Pending' | 'Failed';

type User<T extends RecordX<Status>> = {   // how to default assign
  name: string;
  age: number;
  status: T['Active']
} | {
    error: string;
    id: string;
    status: T['Failed']
  } |
{
  status: T['Pending']
}

const user: User = {   // need the template type parameter
  name: 'foobar';
  age: 99,
  status: 'NotWorking'  // not working
}
```

How to default the first generic parameter, so that user doesn't need to provide the type

Comment: `status: Status`?

Comment: @depperm but how to create conditional user object with specific structure for each status type

Comment: What's the problem? if you try to create a `User`, it will give you type completion if you have typed the other properties. See [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKClAdgQwFsIAuKOYRAS1wHMBubKfW0vAV0ICMlGcL8wdnDIByfAGNgVAG4RRUAPSKoACwD2AdyjB1UVsGbtdE9YTAAbCMAgAaKFWCi4UC1qQT8CAPzfMAXygAHwwmJER1RDIKajo+BwATaMoaBiYBIREoUQAzfCorBNEA4MwsHCok8hS49OBBYTFIXATU4v9MTFNcCihhJABBMngkVFCcAmIxAb6ERFFbOoasgCI8gogElagAxi71HsN+xAAhYbmx8rwiNlEZ44WlzLIVyWk5bd2gA)

Comment: @JuanMendes, i would like to reuse Status Type in other places also, so that why wanted to use same Status inside user type

Comment: I don't see why you're using generics at all here.  Looks like you just want a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJyd6m).  If that *doesn't* meet your needs, please [edit] your code to show a [mre] where it fails.  If it *does* meet your needs, let me know and I can write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz please see my answer, i wanted Status to be DRY

Comment: Your answer repeats things significantly more than [this example](https://tsplay.dev/WJyd6m).  Indeed, your answer is more complicated and produces the same type as the conventional approach shown in my example.  I'd strongly suggest you switch to a plain discriminated union unless you can articulate how your version is comparatively DRY.  Would you like me to post an answer with the conventional solution to this so you can compare it to your unconventional one?  Or do you want to stick with your own method?

Comment: @jcalz please post your answer.

Comment: @jcalz can you help me with this
stackoverflow.com/questions/72254506/typescript-extract-exact-discriminated-conditional-unions-type-in-iterator-metho

Comment: Ugh, I think I misunderstood your question entirely.  Let me try again.  Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wep3KW) meet your needs?  If so I can write up that answer.  If not, could you show some small code example where it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Aside: You keep using the term "conditional type", but there are no [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) in this question.  Do you mean "[union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)" instead?

Comment: @jcalz above link of extracting status from User is simple n easy, thanks for suggesting that approach. yeah its union type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to define `Status` in terms of `User`, instead of doing it the other way around.  That way you don't have to repeat yourself very much, and you don't have to try to get the compiler to autocomplete the individual statuses.  It looks like this:

```
type User = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    status: 'Active'
} | {
    error: string;
    id: string;
    status: 'Failed'
} | {
    id: string;
    status: 'Pending'
}

type Status = User['status'];
// type Status = "Active" | "Failed" | "Pending"
```

By [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the [discriminanted union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type `User` with the `"status"` key, we get the desired [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) for `Status`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gWAFBT1AOwEMBbCALijmEQEsCBzAbh3yiIYsIFcSAjJC1z5qRYNziUA5AEEAxsFoA3CFJwBfKAB8MrfEkQB7RJWp1GQtrQAmpmvWZ68o8ZKhSAYkVoAbCNbVsTS0cLGE8GztzR3CqYDEJaQAFCAJrB0D1HBxQSCgAZXjXVFgERABtKRcJKQBdIQB6Bqhc6EKEuBKAInlFFS7tKC6vX38BnS6UtIcuoA)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `enum` keyword like this:

```
enum Status {
  ACTIVE = 'ACTIVE',
  PENDING = 'PENDING',
  FAILED = 'FAILED',
}

type User = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  status: Status.ACTIVE;
} | {
  error: string;
  id: string;
  status: Status.FAILED;
} |
{
  id: string;
  status: Status.PENDING;
}
```

Later on you can do this to check the `User` typing.

```
const user: User = { ... }

if (user.status === Status.PENDING) {
  // Do something if status is pending
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First converted literal `Status` to object format

```
type Intermediate = {
  Active: 'Active';
  Pending: 'Pending';
  Failed: 'Failed';
}
```

Then assigned as generic type for Status

```
type RecordX<K extends keyof any> = {
  [P in K]: P;
};

type Status = 'Active' | 'Pending' | 'Failed';

type User<T extends RecordX<Status> = RecordX<Status>> = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  status: T['Active']
} | {
  error: string;
  id: string;
  status: T['Failed']
} |
{
  status: T['Pending']
}

const user: User = {
  name: 'foobar';
  age: 99,
  status: 'Active' // autocomplete works
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using `Intermediate` for anything... what does it do?

Comment: Why are you using generic here, do you plan to write `User<XXX>` for some other `XXX`? Or do you just want it to be `RecordX<Status>`?  If so, why not make `User` a non-generic type and hardcode `T` to `RecordX<Status>`?

Comment: @jcalz, how to hardcode T to RecordX<Status> , didn't quite got ur answer. can you post an example.

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/wjnK6w) is an example where I successively simplify what you're doing.  First I remove the generic and hardcode `T` as `RecordX<Status>`.  Then I remove `RecordX` and hardcode `T` as the definition for `RecordX`.  Then I note that `T[K]` is equivalent to `K`, so you can replace `T['Active']` with `'Active'`, etc.  Eventually I end up with the discriminated union type from my answer.

Comment: @v3 look simple